# Bookmarks showing on chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bookmarks

Hi I have Google bookmarks turned off on my desktop computer but I just updated Chrome on my laptop not only did the update not load correctly now I have Google bookmarks across the top of the page, I want to remove them like on my desktop.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you, can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Do you mean bookmark bar?

Answer (score 0):

Just press `ctrl` + `shift` + `B`

I hope this is what you are looking for.